# How do I specify a timeout in sqlite3 from the command-line?

Tags: sqlite

I have a couple basic scripts that kick out a little information while my sqlite3 DB is being populated, but about half the time the command instantly fails:

```
$ sqlite3 outgoing.db "select * from edges where worker is not null;"
Error: database is locked
$ sqlite3 outgoing.db "select * from edges where worker is not null;"
Error: database is locked
$ sqlite3 outgoing.db "select * from edges where worker is not null;"
1014->9000|1014|9000||-1.0|2
1014->9001|1014|9001||-1.0|2
...
```

If I add `.timeout 1;` to the beginning of the command I just get a syntax error; how do I pass sqlite the special `.` parameters non-interactively via the command-line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by using an init file.

`init.sql` (note that the timeout value is in milliseconds - 1 is rather short):

```
.timeout 1000
```

At the prompt:

```
$ sqlite3 -init init.sql outgoing.db "select * from edges where worker is not null;"
Loading resources from init.sql
# 1 second pause
Error: database is locked
```

With some shells (on Linux at least, not very portable), you can avoid the need for a proper file with process substitution if that's a problem:

```
$ sqlite3 -init <(echo .timeout 1000) your.db "your sql;"
```

The extra output line ("Loading resources from ...") doesn't get printed if the output is redirected to a file or pipe, or to the `.output` file if you specified one in your init file.

Answer (score 8):

Just use:

```
$ sqlite3 -cmd ".timeout 1000" outgoing.db "SELECT * FROM edges"
```

Comment: This looks very similar to an already provided answer.

Comment: No, because I am providing dedicated sqlite3 param '-cmd'

Comment: This is actually the most elegant answer because it avoids process substitutions and heredocs.

Answer (score 4):

In the `sqlite3` command-line tool, dot commands are *not* SQL commands, so you cannot mix them with queries *in the same line* (and you should not delimit them with a semicolon).

`sqlite3` can read commands from its standard input, so you can simply use a here document to give it multiple lines:

```sh
$ sqlite3 outgoing.db <<EOF
.timeout 1000
select * from edges where worker is not null;
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this little bash function for it, so that I wouldn't need to make a file:

```
function patient_sqlite {
  DB_FILE="$1"
  QUERY="$2"
  echo $'.timeout 1000\n'"$QUERY" | sqlite3 "$DB_FILE"
}
patient_sqlite db.sqlite 'SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1;'
```